# clickOutside hook triggers on inside select

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, antd

I have a card component which consists of 2 selects and a button, select1 is always shown and select2 is invisible until you press the button changing the state. I also have an onClickOutside hook that reverts the state and hides select2 when you click outside the card.

The problem Im having is that in the case when select2 is visible, if you use any select and click on an option it registers as a click outside the card and hides select2, how can I fix this?

Heres the relevant code from my card component:

```
const divRef = useRef() as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement>;

const [disableSelect2, setDisableSelect2] = useState(true);

const handleActionButtonClick = () => {
    setDisableSelect2(!disableSelect2)
}

useOutsideClick(divRef, () => {
    if (!disableSelect2) {
      setDisableSelect2(!disableSelect2);
    }
});

return (
    <div ref={divRef}>
      <Card>
         <Select1>[options]</Select1>
         !disableSelect2 ? 
           <Select2>[options]</Select2>
         : null
         <div
          className="d-c_r_action-button"
          onClick={handleActionButtonClick}
        >
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And this is my useoutsideClick hook

```
const useOutsideClick = (ref:React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement>, callback:any) => {
  const handleClick = (e:any) => {
    if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(e.target)) {
      callback();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("click", handleClick);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
    };
  });
};
```

Extra informtaion: Im using customized antd components and cant use MaterialUI

Comment: Your handleClick has probably a stale reference to the callback argument

Comment: Ok, how do I solve that?

Comment: You can solve that with [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) for your handleClick function, and put the callback argument in the dependecy array. If I were you I would create a small test component to try out and debug the outside click custom hook, because in your component there is too much stuff going on with your state and your inverted bools to judge whether the custom hook works as expected. I bet the problem was that your callback had a stale closure to some outdated state value.

Comment: Thank you, I tried a more isolated version using the answer below, the hook is working properly but fails when I add antd´s Select to the mix, there must be something internal Im missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to recreate your case from the code you shared. But the version I 'built' works.

Perhaps you can make it fail by adding in other special features from your case and then raise the issue again, or perhaps you could use the working code from there to fix yours?

See the draft of your problem I made at https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-dust-njw0f?file=/src/Component.tsx

[image]

Comment: Yes you are right, Ive been running some tests with your version and it works, until i swapped the basic <select> for antd´s Select, so that must be what is causing the error

Comment: If you feel I've answered correctly I would be obliged if you would mark it as a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Much appreciated. Your tick was the one to give me my 1000 reputation! We can all turn off the internet now :)